# Why does eclipse keep crashing in windowsbuilder design view?

Tags: java, eclipse, windowsbuilder

I have this problem constantly on my laptop.  I usually go into the windowsbuilder GUI and click around, and the program crashes.  Honestly the most annoying thing ever, and I am able to run much more cpu intensive programs on here.  Anybody face this issue and resolve it somehow?

log summary from crash:

```
Command Line: -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8 -Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UseStringDeduplication --add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8 -Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true -Xms256m -Xmx1024m --add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM 

Host: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6300U CPU @ 2.40GHz, 4 cores, 3G,  Windows 10 , 64 bit Build 18362 (10.0.18362.329)
Time: Sat Oct 26 14:48:56 2019 Eastern Daylight Time elapsed time: 244 seconds (0d 0h 4m 4s)
    ---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

    Current thread (0x00000000042c6800):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=11372, stack(0x0000000000c00000,0x0000000000d00000)]

    Stack: [0x0000000000c00000,0x0000000000d00000],  sp=0x0000000000cf8ae0,  free space=994k
    Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
    C  [MSCTF.dll+0x2aca8]
    C  [MSCTF.dll+0x2a6cd]
    C  [MSCTF.dll+0x426c9]
    C  [MSCTF.dll+0x3ca24]
    C  [MSCTF.dll+0x3563d]
    C  [MSCTF.dll+0x3bc5b]
    C  [MSCTF.dll+0x1eaab]
    C  [MSCTF.dll+0x1ed94]
    C  [USER32.dll+0x163ed]
    C  [USER32.dll+0x159fc]
    C  [USER32.dll+0x1238d]
    C  [USER32.dll+0x28972]
    C  [USER32.dll+0x12eb4]
    C  [USER32.dll+0x12cef]
    C  [USER32.dll+0x163ed]
    C  [USER32.dll+0x159fc]
    C  [USER32.dll+0x14e15]
    C  [USER32.dll+0x147f3]
    C  0x00000000145f6ebe

    Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
    J 6439  org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(JIJJ)J (0 bytes) @ 0x00000000145f6e1e [0x00000000145f6dc0+0x000000000000005e]
    J 11969 c2 org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(JIJJ)J (21 bytes) @ 0x0000000014414a78 [0x0000000014414a20+0x0000000000000058]
    J 17209 c2 org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(JIJJ)J (1980 bytes) @ 0x0000000014b6902c [0x0000000014b68e00+0x000000000000022c]
    J 14881 c2 org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(JIJJ)J (50 bytes) @ 0x00000000148b61f8 [0x00000000148b61a0+0x0000000000000058]
    J 7487 c2 org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(JJJJ)J (108 bytes) @ 0x00000000143cffc0 [0x00000000143cff40+0x0000000000000080]
    v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
    J 6439  org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(JIJJ)J (0 bytes) @ 0x00000000145f6e1e [0x00000000145f6dc0+0x000000000000005e]
    J 11969 c2 org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(JIJJ)J (21 bytes) @ 0x0000000014414a78 [0x0000000014414a20+0x0000000000000058]
    J 17209 c2 org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(JIJJ)J (1980 bytes) @ 0x0000000014b6902c [0x0000000014b68e00+0x000000000000022c]
    J 14881 c2 org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(JIJJ)J (50 bytes) @ 0x00000000148b61f8 [0x00000000148b61a0+0x0000000000000058]
    J 7487 c2 org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(JJJJ)J (108 bytes) @ 0x00000000143cffc0 [0x00000000143cff40+0x0000000000000080]
    v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
    j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.ImmSetCompositionFont(JLorg/eclipse/swt/internal/win32/LOGFONT;)Z+0
    j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Caret.setIMEFont()V+109
    j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Caret.setFocus()V+84
    j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.WM_SETFOCUS(JJ)Lorg/eclipse/swt/internal/win32/LRESULT;+29
    J 17209 c2 org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(JIJJ)J (1980 bytes) @ 0x0000000014b6a118 [0x0000000014b68e00+0x0000000000001318]
    J 14881 c2 org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(JIJJ)J (50 bytes) @ 0x00000000148b61f8 [0x00000000148b61a0+0x0000000000000058]
    J 7487 c2 org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(JJJJ)J (108 bytes) @ 0x00000000143cffc0 [0x00000000143cff40+0x0000000000000080]
    v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
    j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.SetFocus(J)J+0
    j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.forceFocus()Z+69
    j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setFocus()Z+18
    j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus()Z+65
    j  org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.multi.SourcePage.setFocus()V+4
    j  org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.multi.DefaultMultiMode.showPage(Lorg/eclipse/wb/core/editor/IEditorPage;)V+100
    j  org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.multi.MultiPagesMode.showSource()V+16
    j  org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage$9.openSourcePosition(I)V+21
    j  org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.gefTree.policy.dblclick.OpenEditorLayoutEditPolicy.performDoubleClick()V+24
    j  org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.gefTree.policy.dblclick.DoubleClickLayoutEditPolicy.performRequest(Lorg/eclipse/wb/gef/core/requests/Request;)V+13
    j  org.eclipse.wb.gef.core.EditPart.performRequest(Lorg/eclipse/wb/gef/core/requests/Request;)V+31
    j  org.eclipse.wb.internal.gef.tree.tools.DoubleClickEditPartTracker.handleDoubleClick(I)V+28
    j  org.eclipse.wb.gef.core.tools.Tool.mouseDoubleClick(Lorg/eclipse/swt/events/MouseEvent;Lorg/eclipse/wb/gef/core/IEditPartViewer;)V+15
    j  org.eclipse.wb.gef.graphical.tools.SelectionTool.mouseDoubleClick(Lorg/eclipse/swt/events/MouseEvent;Lorg/eclipse/wb/gef/core/IEditPartViewer;)V+19
    j  org.eclipse.wb.internal.gef.core.EditDomain.mouseDoubleClick(Lorg/eclipse/swt/events/MouseEvent;Lorg/eclipse/wb/gef/core/IEditPartViewer;)V+17
    j  org.eclipse.wb.internal.gef.tree.TreeEventManager.mouseDoubleClick(Lorg/eclipse/swt/events/MouseEvent;)V+16
    v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
    J 6407  jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; java.base@13 (0 bytes) @ 0x00000000145f4ecf [0x00000000145f4e40+0x000000000000008f]
    J 6282 c1 jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; java.base@13 (104 bytes) @ 0x000000000da822f4 [0x000000000da81640+0x0000000000000cb4]
    J 6331 c2 jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; java.base@13 (10 bytes) @ 0x00000000145e6774 [0x00000000145e6720+0x0000000000000054]
    J 15057 c1 org.eclipse.wb.internal.draw2d.EventManager$8.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (40 bytes) @ 0x000000000e98873c [0x000000000e9882c0+0x000000000000047c]
    j  com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.mouseDoubleClick(Lorg/eclipse/swt/events/MouseEvent;)V+16
    J 11845 c1 org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;)V (1291 bytes) @ 0x000000000e0879ac [0x000000000e081f80+0x0000000000005a2c]
    J 17061 c2 org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;)V (592 bytes) @ 0x0000000014b4be6c [0x0000000014b4bdc0+0x00000000000000ac]
    J 15101 c2 org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/EventTable;Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;)V (34 bytes) @ 0x0000000014a2f630 [0x0000000014a2f4c0+0x0000000000000170]
    J 10559 c1 org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents()Z (109 bytes) @ 0x000000000dd272bc [0x000000000dd26a40+0x000000000000087c]
    J 17785 c1 org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch()Z (94 bytes) @ 0x000000000ee8e2e4 [0x000000000ee8dc80+0x0000000000000664]
    j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run()V+564
    j  org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Lorg/eclipse/core/databinding/observable/Realm;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+12
    j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(Lorg/eclipse/e4/ui/model/application/MApplicationElement;Lorg/eclipse/e4/core/contexts/IEclipseContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+57
    j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(Lorg/eclipse/e4/ui/model/application/MApplicationElement;)V+20
    j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display;Lorg/eclipse/ui/application/WorkbenchAdvisor;[I)V+379
    j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$$Lambda$109.run()V+12
    j  org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Lorg/eclipse/core/databinding/observable/Realm;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+12
    j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display;Lorg/eclipse/ui/application/WorkbenchAdvisor;)I+16
    j  org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display;Lorg/eclipse/ui/application/WorkbenchAdvisor;)I+2
    j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(Lorg/eclipse/equinox/app/IApplicationContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+113
    j  org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+138
    j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+85
    j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+82
    j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+105
    j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run([Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)Ljava/lang/Object;+132
    v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
    j  jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0 java.base@13
    j  jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+100 java.base@13
    j  jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6 java.base@13
    j  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+59 java.base@13
    j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework([Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/net/URL;)V+201
    j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun([Ljava/lang/String;)V+159
    j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run([Ljava/lang/String;)I+4
    v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

    siginfo: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005), reading address 0x0000000000000020
Register to memory mapping:

RIP=0x00007ffc3deaaca8 MSCTF.dll
RAX=0x0 is NULL
RBX=0x0000000027e5e9f0 points into unknown readable memory: 78 31 f7 3d fc 7f 00 00
RCX=0x000000002d234c10 points into unknown readable memory: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
RDX=0x0000000000000002 is an unknown value
RSP=0x0000000000cf8ae0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000042c6800
RBP=0x0 is NULL
RSI=0x0 is NULL
RDI=0x0000000040000000 is pointing into metadata
R8 =0x000000002bd227c0 points into unknown readable memory: 30 2e f7 3d fc 7f 00 00
R9 =0x0 is NULL
R10=0x000000000167a0c0 points into unknown readable memory: 01 00 00 00 5e 23 7e 23
R11=0x0 is NULL
R12=
[error occurred during error reporting (printing register info), id 0xc0000005, EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffbfe38872f]

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000000, RBX=0x0000000027e5e9f0, RCX=0x000000002d234c10, RDX=0x0000000000000002
RSP=0x0000000000cf8ae0, RBP=0x0000000000000000, RSI=0x0000000000000000, RDI=0x0000000040000000
R8 =0x000000002bd227c0, R9 =0x0000000000000000, R10=0x000000000167a0c0, R11=0x0000000000000000
R12=0x00000000ffffffff, R13=0x0000000000560183, R14=0x0000000000000000, R15=0x0000000000000000
RIP=0x00007ffc3deaaca8, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010202

Top of Stack: (sp=0x0000000000cf8ae0)
0x0000000000cf8ae0:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x0000000000cf8af0:   0000000008200000 0000000000cf8d00
0x0000000000cf8b00:   00007ffc3ed07d00 00007ffc3c688ba3
0x0000000000cf8b10:   0000000000000000 00007ffc00000000
0x0000000000cf8b20:   0000000000cf9240 0000000000000001
0x0000000000cf8b30:   0000c1973cfd97bf 0000000000000000
0x0000000000cf8b40:   0000000000000001 0000000000000001
0x0000000000cf8b50:   0000000000000000 0000000000000002
0x0000000000cf8b60:   0000000027e5ea28 00007ffc3deaa6cd
0x0000000000cf8b70:   0000000000000000 0000000000000002
0x0000000000cf8b80:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x0000000000cf8b90:   0000000000000000 00007ffc3ea7a7da
0x0000000000cf8ba0:   00000000230a7400 00007ffc3ea35810
0x0000000000cf8bb0:   0000000000000000 000000003b2fca70
0x0000000000cf8bc0:   000000000000000f 000000002bcd5de0
0x0000000000cf8bd0:   0000000000010702 0000000000cf8d40 

Instructions: (pc=0x00007ffc3deaaca8)
0x00007ffc3deaaba8:   00 00 48 85 c9 74 1e 48 8b 01 48 8b 40 30 83 bb
0x00007ffc3deaabb8:   10 01 00 00 00 8b 93 e8 00 00 00 41 0f 95 c1 ff
0x00007ffc3deaabc8:   15 fb 0e 0d 00 48 8b 8b 30 01 00 00 48 85 c9 0f
0x00007ffc3deaabd8:   85 15 f8 02 00 89 bb f0 00 00 00 e9 79 fe ff ff
0x00007ffc3deaabe8:   4c 89 6c 24 68 4c 8b e6 4c 8b ab a8 00 00 00 4d
0x00007ffc3deaabf8:   8b 7e 08 49 8b 2e 41 8b 76 10 89 bb f0 00 00 00
0x00007ffc3deaac08:   4d 85 ed 0f 85 d5 f5 02 00 49 83 c6 18 89 bb f0
0x00007ffc3deaac18:   00 00 00 49 83 ec 01 75 cf 8b 74 24 38 33 ed 4c
0x00007ffc3deaac28:   8b 6c 24 68 44 8b fd 85 f6 0f 8e e1 fc ff ff 48
0x00007ffc3deaac38:   8b bb 58 02 00 00 41 bf 01 00 00 00 48 85 ff 0f
0x00007ffc3deaac48:   84 cb fc ff ff e9 d7 f5 02 00 0f 1f 40 00 66 66
0x00007ffc3deaac58:   0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 8b c6 0f af 47 3c 4c 63
0x00007ffc3deaac68:   f0 4c 03 77 30 49 8b 0e 48 85 c9 74 0d 48 8b 01
0x00007ffc3deaac78:   48 8b 40 10 ff 15 46 0e 0d 00 49 8b 4e 08 48 85
0x00007ffc3deaac88:   c9 74 0d 48 8b 01 48 8b 40 10 ff 15 30 0e 0d 00
0x00007ffc3deaac98:   ff c6 3b 77 38 0f 8d 8e fd ff ff eb bb 48 8b 01
0x00007ffc3deaaca8:   48 8b 40 20 e9 05 ff ff ff 4d 8b 66 48 4d 85 e4
0x00007ffc3deaacb8:   0f 85 c0 f5 02 00 4d 8b 76 18 4d 85 f6 0f 84 5d
0x00007ffc3deaacc8:   fc ff ff eb e4 0f 1f 00 8b 47 64 0f af c6 48 63
0x00007ffc3deaacd8:   c8 48 03 4f 58 83 79 04 00 74 1a 48 8b 49 08 48
0x00007ffc3deaace8:   85 c9 74 11 48 8b 01 ba 01 00 00 00 48 8b 00 ff
0x00007ffc3deaacf8:   15 cb 0d 0d 00 ff c6 3b 77 60 0f 8d 42 fd ff ff
0x00007ffc3deaad08:   eb c6 ff 15 40 06 0d 00 e9 42 fd ff ff cc cc cc
0x00007ffc3deaad18:   cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc 48 89 5c 24 08 57 48 83
0x00007ffc3deaad28:   ec 20 48 8d 05 4f 92 0c 00 8b da 48 89 01 48 8b
0x00007ffc3deaad38:   f9 e8 62 f7 ff ff 48 8d 05 4b 92 0c 00 48 89 07
0x00007ffc3deaad48:   f6 c3 01 74 09 48 8b cf ff 15 fa 05 0d 00 48 8b
0x00007ffc3deaad58:   5c 24 30 48 8b c7 48 83 c4 20 5f c3 cc cc cc cc
0x00007ffc3deaad68:   cc cc cc cc 40 53 48 83 ec 20 48 8d 05 d7 91 0c
0x00007ffc3deaad78:   00 48 8b d9 48 89 01 48 8d 05 f2 91 0c 00 83 61
0x00007ffc3deaad88:   18 00 48 83 61 10 00 83 61 1c 00 48 89 41 08 ff
0x00007ffc3deaad98:   15 8b 05 0d 00 48 89 43 20 48 8d 05 f8 91 0c 00 


Stack slot to memory mapping:
stack at sp + 0 slots: 0x0 is NULL
stack at sp + 1 slots: 0x0 is NULL
stack at sp + 2 slots: 0x0000000008200000 points into unknown readable memory: 00 05 0e 66 07 05 27 fa
stack at sp + 3 slots: 0x0000000000cf8d00 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000042c6800
stack at sp + 4 slots: 0x00007ffc3ed07d00 combase.dll
stack at sp + 5 slots: 0x00007ffc3c688ba3 KERNELBASE.dll
stack at sp + 6 slots: 0x0 is NULL
stack at sp + 7 slots: 0x00007ffc00000000 is an unknown value
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? If whole JVM crashed crash report file: `hs_err_pid*.log` should be generated in eclipse directory.

Comment: yeah I got the log file:

Comment: Can you attach whole file? Or, at least, few top frames from crashing thread.

Comment: yeah, just pasted the thread portion of the log.

Comment: What version of _Eclipse_ are you using?

Comment: Version: 2019-09 4.13.0

Comment: Did you install the [latest version](https://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/latest/) of _WindowBuilder_? Did you try the _WindowBuilder_ [forum](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/f/214/)?

Comment: Possibly bug [551677](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=551677) fixed in 2019-12 M1